# Performance difference between AngularJS and MVC 5 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

We have developed a sample page which will display 50 images on page load.
We calculated load time(time from request initialization till result get returned) i.e. does not include time to paint those images on browser.

In both approach i.e. MVC and AngularJS we have used same function which will return same data , only difference is that in MVC we returned model which is binded to view and in AngularJS we returned JSONResult which will bind to AngularMarkup.

We are hoping that we will get good result with AngularJS but surprisingly MVC done better?
For AngularJS we have used Module/Controller/Service approach for calling method to return data.

So what will be cause of this? Is it implementation problem or something else is changing result.

Note: JMETER is used by Testing team for performance calculation with 500 uers at a time.

Comment: What is your measure factors?  As long as you are talking about AngularJS, number of people hitting to website does not matter because it is all about client side. Data on the wire reaching to browser would be always smaller for AngularJS case since you are only using JSON. On the other hand, browser you are using key factor since it will be the handling heavy loading of Angular data-binding and calculations.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi Thank you for explanation. As I am developer , I dont have more information related to JMETER . But I think main measure is loading images , js and returning result to view is key concern.

Comment: Does it make difference that I am converting data in JSON format in AngularJS service call i.e. Action written to return images data, is taking lot of time compare to plain MVC model passed to view.

Comment: If you are complaining about image loading time, it is not AngularJS fault. In MVC, when you return html to your browser, as soon as it finds images it starts to download them. In AngularJS way you first load your JSON and browser will start downloading. You can check this article for image preloading in angular; http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2597-preloading-images-in-angularjs-with-promises.htm